# MySql - unable to connect as root

Tags: mysql

I have need to connect to mySql server 5.5 and create database using command line. Ideally it would be using a UI utility but I don't have it.  Here is an issue:

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

However I definitely set password while I was installing MySql server.

What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect with `sudo mysql -u root -p` and it will prompt you for the password. The key here is the `-p` option. You can also provide the password as part of the command with the `-p` option, but that is considered a security risk, since the password will be stored in clear text in your commands history.

Comment: " since the password will be stored in clear text in your commands history". Not if you start with a space. It WILL show up in your process list too though so it is still unwise to do so.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "start with a space"?

Comment: yes sir. Commands that start with a space do not end up in `history`. `mysql -u user -p` vs. `{space}mysql -u user -p`

Comment: Interesting feature! Does not work in Fedora/Red Hat family.

Answer (score 0):

Also; if you need a GUI, you may use either Webmin available from http://www.webmin.com/ or MySQL workbench available at http://www.mysql.com/